# Audio not playing through Java on Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio, java, audio-playback

#### The issue

I'm trying to play sound on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ through Java, but it doesn't work. I have

1. Written code (shown below) in IntelliJ, and confirmed that it works on Windows 10.
2. Connected speakers to my Raspberry Pi through aux and

   - Used `sudo raspi-config` to set audio to "headphones" (the only option).
   - Confirmed they work with `aplay my-file.wav`.
3. Attempted to run my code (through Gradle) with `gradle run` in the project directory. It displays the text "Playing audio" as expected, but no audio plays.
4. Tried the advice in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424757/set-audio-output-using-command-line) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377129/playing-audio-on-raspberry-pi-with-java) and [this forum](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=278665) (hence my audio testing above), all to no avail.

#### My entire code

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
        File file = new File("my-file.wav");
        AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioStream);
        System.out.println("Playing audio");
        clip.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

#### Other info

I'm connecting to my Pi over SSH from Windows. My `java --version` is

```
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-post-Raspbian-2deb10u1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-post-Raspbian-2deb10u1, mixed mode)
```

My `gradle --version` is `Gradle 6.8.3`. I'm using Gradle because the real project I'm working on requires it (this one is obviously just a demo).

I'm interested in any solution whatsoever to use Java to play sound. Is there a way to simply have Java call another bit of code that does work?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377129/playing-audio-on-raspberry-pi-with-java/30520683

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that works for me: replacing all the lines that create and start the `AudioInputStream` and `Clip` with this one line:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("aplay my-file.wav");
```

Note: I have intentionally not marked this answer correct, because it does not solve the issue with `AudioInputStream`. It simply sidesteps the problem, by passing the issue of playing audio to the `aplay` command in terminal. Thus, it is not a solution, but it might nonetheless be helpful to someone who just wants to play some sound with Java on a pi, no matter how hacky the approach.

Interestingly, I also found that this breaks for any file path with spaces, and I have absolutely no idea why. I tried enclosing the path in single quotes and double quotes, and escaping spaces with backslashes, and all of those together. Nothing worked. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943232/path-with-spaces) a related question without a definitive answer.